# Is there a way to find the pendingReuests in new angular apps

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I'm trying to automate an angular app using selenium. Before running the selenium script I would want to wait for the app to completely load. I used the following code to do this, but after the app was updated to a new angular version, I'm not able to get the pending requests using this method.
I tried searching for a solution for a few days, but couldn't find any. Thanks in advance :)

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length.toString();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For which version of AngularJS are you having the problem. And what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Angular, you can access [Pending Requests from the built-in HTTP$](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#pendingRequests) directly

Or if you want to wrap it in a service look [ref from here](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/BWw3eL)/below

```
angular.module('app', [])
// This service keeps track of pending requests
.service('pendingRequests', function() {
  var pending = [];
  this.get = function() {
    return pending;
  };
  this.add = function(request) {
    pending.push(request);
  };
  this.remove = function(request) {
    pending = _.filter(pending, function(p) {
      return p.url !== request;
    });
  };
  this.cancelAll = function() {
    angular.forEach(pending, function(p) {
      p.canceller.resolve();
    });
    pending.length = 0;
  };
})
// This service wraps $http to make sure pending requests are tracked 
.service('httpService', ['$http', '$q', 'pendingRequests', function($http, $q, pendingRequests) {
  this.get = function(url) {
    var canceller = $q.defer();
    pendingRequests.add({
      url: url,
      canceller: canceller
    });
    //Request gets cancelled if the timeout-promise is resolved
    var requestPromise = $http.get(url, { timeout: canceller.promise });
    //Once a request has failed or succeeded, remove it from the pending list
    requestPromise.finally(function() {
      pendingRequests.remove(url);
    });
    return requestPromise;
  }
}])
```